RF MEMS (Radio Frequency Micro-Electro-Mechanical Systems) Switches
RF Reflection Damage.  What would the artifacts at the contact beam areas looks like under a SEM examine?  More like arc damage or diffused or have a burned thermal damage appearance?  Thanks Charles R.
